# Associated entity being persisted but no cascade option setted

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In doctrine documentation I found: "By default, no operations are cascaded." (here http://bit.ly/1frPyLH)
But still one of my database entities is persisting it's associated objects, besides the fact that it has no cascade option in the association. 
How can I prevent it from persisting the associated entities ?

Comment: Can you provide the code defining your entity (php annotations or yml) and the code persisting your entity?

Comment: Never had this problem and I would trust the doc on this. Are you absolutely sure you aren't using persist() on your associated entities beforehand ? Anyhow please post the controller code / entity relationship for better assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true and the documentation is still not wrong. =P

Without going deeper on your problem, you need to be aware that by default Doctrine applies a concept called "persistence by reachability". This means that if you are creating a new entity and one of your associations is already managed by UnitOfWork (already known by Doctrine), it will "cascade" the operation.
The problem here is how you read about cascading. In reality, it's not the cascading factor that is updating the associated entity, but it's because it's already managed by Doctrine.

To solve this "problem", you need to modify the way you want Doctrine to deal with your entities by altering the [Change Tracking Policy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html).

I hope this gives you enough information to solve your issue.